# Applying a spacing between different cells

Tags: html, css-tables

I was trying to put some horizontal spacing between the table cells here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mVX93/43/

However the only thing I was able to do to get it to appear correctly was to put a thick border the same colour of the background a bit like this:

```
border: 10px solid gray;
```

Is there not a better way to put spacing between the cells?

Comment: Add `cellspacing="10px"` to table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
#my-table td{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Remove this line

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

to see your space between cells better

Comment: The border is so thin though, 1px, anyway to put a bigger space?

Comment: This adds spacing *inside* each cell, not between cells. The difference matters e.g. if borders are used.

Comment: Jimmy If you want bigger space, change 10px to bigger number  
@JukkaK.Korpela Well, you are right but I really have never seen real space between cells. If that is possible, then maybe the border are split into two borders and there is space between them (which I have never saw before)